# Downloads in high speed with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, download-manager

Is there any plug-in or something which is the same as DownThemAll for Firefox? Just need to have a kind of download manager for Chrome but better that Chrome has built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative download managers like [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/board/viewtopic.php?t=10815) can integrate with Google Chrome and take over downloads, but I'm not sure which other download manager is capable of downloading all links like DownThemAll for Firefox